# VB.net XmlDocument .selectNodes

Tags: vb.net, xpath, xmldocument

How can i read/write Node N3 id=n

```
docY.LoadXml(RecXml)
docY.selectNode("/N1/N2/N3 ....
```

RecXML:

```
<N1>
    <id><1></id>
    <N2>
      <N3 id="1" ><Testo 1></N3>
      <N3 id="2" ><Testo 2></N3>
    </N2>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I found the answer.

docY.selectNode("/N1/N2/N3[@ud='1'")

Comment: docY.selectNode("/N1/N2/N3[@id='1']")